# OOP opencv trackbar

Tags: c++, oop, opencv

I am trying to make [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html) OOP, so I made a class that implements the callback function for the trackbar.

This is my class

```
class Contours
{
public:
    static Mat src_gray;
    static int thresh;
Contours(Mat, int);
~Contours(void);
static void callback(int, void* );

private:
};

Contours::Contours(Mat src_gray,int thresh){
this->src_gray=src_gray;
this->thresh=thresh;

}
Contours::~Contours(void){}

void Contours::callback(int, void*)
{int largest_area=0;
int largest_contour_index=0;
Mat canny_output;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

/// Detect edges using canny
Canny( src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );
/// Find contours
findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

/// Draw contours
Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
cout<<contours.size()<<endl;
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
{
    double a=contourArea( contours[i],false);  //  Find the area of contour
    if(a>largest_area){
        largest_area=a;
        largest_contour_index=i;  }              //Store the index of largest contour

    //Scalar color = Scalar(255,255,255 );
    //drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );

}
cout<<"cnt maxim: "<<largest_contour_index<<endl;

    Scalar color = Scalar(255,255,255 );
    drawContours( drawing, contours, largest_contour_index, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );

/// Show in a window
namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow( "Contours", drawing );
//imwrite("sada.png",drawing);
}
```

And calling the function

```
createTrackbar( " Canny thresh:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, &Contours::callback );
```

I get

Error   5   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class cv::Mat Contours::src_gray" (?src_gray@Contours@@2VMat@cv@@A)   D:\Licenta\Hand sign recognition\Algoritmi.obj  Hand sign recognition

Error   6   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int Contours::thresh" (?thresh@Contours@@2HA) D:\Licenta\Hand sign recognition\Algoritmi.obj  Hand sign recognition

Any ideas why?

Comment: Those are linker errors. Your code compiles and it's probably a project setup issue. A good think with visual studio is that you can search to find out what their error codes mean (such as LNK2001).

Comment: Have you included imgproc and highui libraries?

Comment: please lookup, how to *define* static variables in a class (yours are only *declared* )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe use a different approach to the 'static callback' problem:

```
class Contours
{
public:
    Mat src_gray; // non-static
    int thresh;
    Contours(Mat, int);
    void callback(int, void* ); // non-static
};

void callback(int value, void*ptr)  // static global
{
   Contours* cnt = (Contours*)ptr;  // cast 'this'
   cnt->callback(value,0);          // call non-static member
}


int main()
{
    Mat gray = ...
    Contours cnt(gray,17);
    // now pass the address of cnt as additional void* Ptr:
    createTrackbar( " Canny thresh:", "Source", &thresh, max_thresh, callback, &cnt );
   ...
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, just don't understand the &cnt parameter, where did it came from and why do I need to put it there.

Comment: feed the address of your contours object into createTrackbar(), then you get it passed back in the callback function.